# Ignore user input when UI is busy

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I will simulate my problem by taking two buttons in a sample application. In my actual case I have a UserControl along with a tabcontrol. When a button is pressed on the UserControl I am trying to get the parent Window and disabling it and perform some work on the UI for 1 minute. After the UI is free I am enabling the parent window.

My problem is when the ParentWindow is disabled and when the user clicks on the tabcontrol, as long as the UI is busy it remains unresponsive. But as soon as the UI does its work, all the user input is being taken into account and it switches tabs by itself. I want to ignore user input when the UI is busy please help. Any suggestions?

In the sample application here is the xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Height="20" Width="180" Click="Button_Click"
                >Hello</Button>
        <Button Height="20" Width="180" Click="Button_Click_1">Do Nothing</Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

In the xaml.cs file here is code. See that I am disabling the Window but when the button is pressed i get the hello message automatically after the UI is free.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window.GetWindow(this).IsEnabled=false;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Window.GetWindow(this).IsEnabled=true;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  It's standard Windows behaviour

Comment: That was the new requirement that the entire UI should be disabled. Otherwise clicking multiple times on that tab control makes the application go to some crazy state and crash..

Comment: It sounds like you want to flush the Windows event queue after you finish the long running work, but before you enable the controls. A randomly selected article on the topic is [here](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2015/08/flush-click-events-in-c/).

Comment: Then fix your app so it doesn’t crash.   Locking out the mouse isn’t the answer

Comment: @HABO 1) do no mess WinForms and WPF 2) do not invent bicycle 3) see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just run your long-running-code in new thread

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    Window.GetWindow(this).IsEnabled = false;
                });
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    Window.GetWindow(this).IsEnabled = true;
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

expected result

[image]